# Background Color breaks in mobile view in Lightning Community

Tags: css, lightning-community, community-builder

I have a lightning community based on the Self Service template. I set up a background image and color for login pages:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I activated and published my community. Now when I go the login page from **desktop** everything is fine:

[image]

However, when this page is viewed on a mobile device (or simulated via Dev Tools in browser) the color overlay disappears:

1. Toggle the device view:
   [image]
2. Refresh the page while in the mobile view to see the result:
   [image]